# Are there any open source app virtualization solutions for Windows

Tags: virtualization, open-source

I am looking for open source solutions that provide application virtualization for Windows! In other words an open source to ThinApp from VMWare.

I have found several commercial options, but nothing open source:

http://www.microsoft.com/systemcenter/appv/dynamic.mspx

http://www.vmware.com/products/thinapp/overview.html

Answer (score 5, accepted):

After some searching I was able to find one open source project:
http://code.google.com/p/appstract/

Haven't tested it, but is open source.

Comment: Only download here is a PDF file. No programs.

Answer (score 11):

[Cameyo](http://cameyo.com/) offers free Application Virtualization and works very well. VirtualBox is typically used for OS virtualization.

Comment: An important note of caution about Cameyo -- it includes this "red flag" on its download page ( http://cameyo.com/download.aspx ):  "... some heuristics anti-viruses are reported to trigger false detections on Cameyo's executables ..."

Comment: You are correct. I will add that in my testing, the only 2 antivirus vendors that have flagged anything were Trend Micro and the free version of AVG (The paid version offers no such balking at the files, oddly enough). Both of those so far were only triggered by Skype.

Comment: @Amartel:  AVG-free detects it, but AVG-paid doesn't?  That is really odd.  Were you using the same versions of the virus signature files (I'm only curious, that's all)?

Comment: I was shocked myself, but have been able to reproduce it 100% of the time. Only package so effected was Skype. I have only tested about 2 dozen apps, but the rest work flawlessly. And yes, both DBs were the most current. I sent a report to AVG for this, but never received a response.

Comment: I am looking for open source solution, and I am a littl eunclear if they are open source or not.

Comment: Sorry, I often use "open source" and "free" interchangably. It is not open source as in code freely available, no.

Comment: @Amartel:  In my strong opinion, if an Anti-Virus company isn't interested in verifying false positives, then their process for handling reports of new viruses may not be any better.  I'm surprised to learn of this though because AVG is well-known and seems to be fairly popular (I suspect the free edition likely helps this along in a big way).

Comment: Now why can't all my apps be virtualised like this? This is awesome! It makes changing computers or reinstalling computers or managing multiple computers so easy! Although.. how does it handle updates?

Comment: This does not seem to be a free program.

Answer (score 0):

Open source [Ulteo](http://www.ulteo.com)'s Open Virtual Desktop has both VDI and Application Virtualization. For Windows, you could have only Application Server, available for 2003/2008 x86/x64.

Comment: I can not find that Ulteo software you told about on your link. It is a french site about something like security or similar.

Answer (score -2):

[sandboxie.com](http://www.sandboxie.com/)  is the best one I have ran across. It let you virtualize an app creating a sandbox around it. After installing it creates an icon for a virtualized version of IE automatically.

Answer (score -3):

[VirtualBox](http://www.virtualbox.org/) will do the job very nicely on both 32-bit and 64-bit editions of Windows XP, Vista, Windows 7, 2003, and 2008.  It is free, and open source, and it works very well to virtualize a wide range of 32-bit and 64-bit Operating Systems.

Comment: I think he meant App virtualization, not OS virtualization.

Comment: @geoffc:  Hmm, you may be right.  =D

Comment: I am looking for app virtualization, and virtualbox is OS virtualization.

Comment: App virtualization is quite different from OS Vz

Comment: Sorry @GeorgeU, I see now that I must've misread your question.  Perhaps this might be helpful (depending on what it is you're trying to do -- I'm hoping this effort at least makes up for my error)?  Quite a few people have been recommending Sandboxie ( http://www.sandboxie.com/ ) to me over the past few months.  Now, I can't determine whether it's open source, and there seems to be a "paid for" version, but they do appear to provide a free version.  If all you're after is isolation, then this (or, better yet, an open source alternative) might be a helpful one to look at.

Comment: -1. Your answer is unfortunately mistaken. Also, you meant well with your comment, but according to [the "Sandboxie" Wikipedia article](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Sandboxie), Sandboxie is actually not open-source. I do encourage you to delete your answer.