# How to share only one window/application to other user in network?

Tags: vnc, remote-control, screen-sharing

I know VNC, windows remote control can share screen to others.

Can I just share one window/application to my buddy and give control of this window/application to him? Same time, I still want to operate the other windows I have.

If I choose to share desktop to him, I can't do anything while he is working on my desktop screen.

Any suggestion is appreciated!

Thanks,
Wei

Comment: http://shared-app-vnc.sourceforge.net/

Answer (score 3, accepted):

This is called application virtualization.

The quick answer is that normal systems don't support hosting one app allowing interaction with the rest of the system by a different user.

If your friend just needs quick access to an app for a short period of time, most teleconference tools (WebEx and the like) allow sharing of only one app and allow the users to interact with that app.

If you absolutely need to set up a virtualized application while allowing interaction by yourself with the system seperately, you'll need to set up an application virtualization server.

Various Application Virtualization systems are discussed on this question: [Are there any open source app virtualization solutions for Windows](https://superuser.com/questions/282261/are-there-any-open-source-app-virtualization-solutions-for-windows)

A google search for "open source application virtualization" should also return some useful results.

Answer (score 5):

The solution is named [VDM](http://ynea.futureware.at/cgi-bin/virtual_display_manager.pl) (Virtual Display Manager).
It works as a set of two programs:

- The **Server** program:

[image: Server]

- The **Client** program:

[image: Client]

It works perfect, but it has a possible security flaw, depending on your desired behavior: it allows access to every window (the server side can not restrict):

[image: Access to every window]

Answer (score 2):

I haven't tried it myself but [SharedAppVnc](http://shared-app-vnc.sourceforge.net/) claims to do exactly what you are asking for.

Comment: for Macs this appears to only be supported on PowerPC?

Comment: Yes, it appears so. It probably wouldn't be a big deal to recompile an Intel version for Mac, but you'd probably have to do that yourself since the project seems to be dead.

Comment: Tested and have not been able to make it work on Windows 7 SP1: the TightVNV Server stops working (general failure).

Answer (score 2):

You may wanna try [Xpra](http://xpra.org/). I was looking on Ubuntu for a X11 forwarding replacement, this is the best thing I found. They have a download for Windows - never tried that one tho.

Answer (score 0):

IMO, Teamviwer is the best option here. You can download Teamviewer [here](http://www.teamviewer.com/en/download/index.aspx).

Teamviewer's QuickConnect feature does **exactly that**.

It can be enabled and disabled under the Advanced options.

Comment: Looks like that feature was discontinued, see: https://community.teamviewer.com/English/discussion/3731/quickconnect-and-or-sharing-single-application  *" it used to be there, but it underutilized, so we chose to discontinue the part of the product."* [sic]