# Restrict access to windows user account to only one program

Tags: windows-7, remote-desktop

I have a Windows 7 PC and i need to give access to it to another person remotely via RDP. I'm going to make a seperate user account for them.

I need to restrict this user to be only able to open chrome. They shouldn't be able to open any other programs or settings or access any data on the PC. Is there a way to do this?

Comment: easiest part of your job would be creating user, defining for this user shell to be chrome; definitely remove user from built-in users group, if it works for you add him to built-in guests - then his profile will be cleaned after each log-off. And then you can set all kinds off additional granulated settings for that user - depends on a level of paranoia :) cause by normal means, if you disable him start menu, run and windows explorer - should be fine

Comment: https://superuser.com/questions/360426/how-to-share-only-one-window-application-to-other-user-in-network  I think to do this with RDP, you'd need to be running Windows Server.  2008R2 and later and make user of Remote Desktop Services (https://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/dd560650(v=ws.10).aspx).

Comment: Did you look at AppLocker: https://blogs.technet.microsoft.com/askpfeplat/2016/06/27/applocker-another-layer-in-the-defense-in-depth-against-malware/ ?